# How to use rbenv with passenger?

Tags: passenger, rbenv

I have a hard time trying to figure out how to use `rbenv` along with `passenger`. I'm running `debian 6`, so I installed `passenger` from `oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com` repository. Then I installed `rbenv`, `ruby-build` and `ruby` and `sinatra`. Then I created a test application.

`nginx.conf`:

```
server {
    server_name a1;
    root   /home/yuri/a1/public;
    access_log   /var/log/nginx/a1-access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/a1-error.log;
    passenger_ruby   /home/yuri/.rbenv/shims/ruby;
    passenger_enabled   on;
}
```

`~/a1/config.ru`:

```
require './app'
run Sinatra::Application
```

`~/a1/app.rb`:

```
require 'sinatra'
get '/' do
    "Hello World!"
end
```

Here's what I see in [browser](http://sprunge.us/fXZS), and in [error.log](http://sprunge.us/BhKJ).

Comment: Your Passenger config snippet actually looks correct. I'm not sure why it doesn't work, I'm not familiar enough with rbenv. It has probably got something to do with environment variables that rbenv expects, but that aren't available when the app is run through Passenger.

Comment: I've already found the solution. The problem was that I didn't specify which ruby to use. As such, `rbenv` decided to use system `ruby-1.8`, installed with `passenger`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to specify application-specific version of `ruby`:

```
$ cd ~/a1
$ rbenv local 1.9.3-p385
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit/create the passenger.conf file

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/conf.d/mod-http-passenger.conf
```

Tell Passenger to use Rbenv setup. It may contain a line pointing to the Ruby version included with Passenger, just delete or comment it out.

```
passenger_ruby /home/yuri/.rbenv/shims/ruby;
passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
```

From [How to Install and Configure Ruby With Rbenv, Rails, MariaDB, Nginx, SSL and Passenger on Ubuntu 17.04](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-and-configure-ruby-with-rbenv-rails-mariadb-nginx-ssl-and-passenger-on-ubuntu-17-04)